# Map of generic interfaces in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I stuck with some simple thing) Let's say I have following:

```
interface IMessagePayload // marker interface

data class IdPayload(
    val id: Long
) : IMessagePayload

data class StringPayload(
    val id: String,
) : IMessagePayload
```

Then I have a class:

```
data class Message<T : IMessagePayload>(
    val id: String,
    val payload: T,
)
```

Also I have some interface describing processor of this message:

```
interface IMessageProcessor<T : IMessagePayload> {
    fun process(message: Message<T>)
}
```

And some implementation:

```
class ProcessorImpl : IMessageProcessor<IdPayload> {
    override fun process(message: Message<IdPayload>) {
    }
}
```

Now I wanna have a map of such processors. Lets use some enum type as a keys of this map:

```
enum class ActionType {
     UPDATE,
     DELETE,
     ADD
}
private var map = mutableMapOf<ActionType, IMessageProcessor<IMessagePayload>>()

map[ActionType.ADD] = ProcessorImpl() // <-- error here
```

And that's where the problem occurs. I cannot put my ProcessorImpl into this map. The compiler says that there is an error: **Type mismatch. Required: IMessageProcessor. Found: ProcessorImpl()**.

I could declare the map in the following way (using star projection):

```
private var map = mutableMapOf<ActionType, IMessageProcessor<*>>()
```

But in this case I cannot call processors's process method fetching it from the map by key first:

```
map[ActionType.ADD]?.process(Message("message-id", IdPayload(1))) // <-- error here
```

Compiler complains: Type mismatch. Required nothing. Found `Message<IdPayload>`

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance).

`IMessageProcessor` is defined as `interface IMessageProcessor<T : IMessagePayload>`; it has one type parameter, which must be `IMessagePayload` or a subtype.

But it is invariant in that type parameter; an `IMessageProcessor< IdPayload>` is not related to an `IMessageProcessor<IMessagePayload>`.  In particular, it's not a subtype.

And your `map` is defined with a value type `IMessageProcessor<IMessagePayload>`.  So its value cannot be an `IMessageProcessor< IdPayload>`, because that's neither the value type, nor a subtype.  Hence the compile error.

---

In this case, the simplest way to get it to compile is to change your `map`:

```
private var map = mutableMapOf<ActionType, IMessageProcessor<out IMessagePayload>>()
```

The only difference there is the `out`; that tells the compiler that the value `IMessageProcessor` is covariant in its type parameter.  (It may help to think of `out` as meaning ‘…or any subtype’.  Similarly, you could make it contravariant by using `in`, which you might think of as ‘…or any supertype’.)

This lets you store in the map an `IMessageProcessor` for any subtype of `IMessagePayload`.

However, if you do that, you'll find that you can't *use* any value you pull out of your map — because it can't tell which messages the processor can handle, i.e. which subtype of `IMessagePayload` it works for!  (The compiler expresses this as expecting a type parameter of `Nothing`.)

In general, it's often better to specify variance on the interface or superclass itself ([declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)) rather than the [use-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) shown above.  But I can't see a good way to do that here, because you have multiple generic classes, and they interact in a complicated way…)

---

Think for a moment what `IMessageProcessor`'s type parameter *means*: it's the type of message that the processor can consume.  So an `IMessageProcessor<A>` can handle messages of type `Message<A>`.

Now, a subtype must be able to do everything its supertype can do (and usually more) — otherwise you can't drop that subtype anywhere that's expecting to use the supertype.  (That has the grand name of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) — but it's really just common sense.)

So an `IMessageProcessor<B>` is a subtype of `IMessageProcessor<A>` only if it can handle at least all the messages that an `IMessageProcessor<A>` can.  This means it must accept all messages of type `Message<A>`.

But `Message` is invariant in its type parameter: a `Message<B>` is not directly related to a `Message<A>`.  So you can't write a processor that handles them both.

The most natural solution I can find is to specify variance on both `Message` and `IMessageProcessor`:

```
data class Message<out T : IMessagePayload>( /*…*/ )

interface IMessageProcessor<in T : IMessagePayload> { /*…*/ }
```

And then use a wildcard in your map to make it explicit that you don't know anything about the type parameters of its values:

```
private var map = mutableMapOf<ActionType, IMessageProcessor<*>>()
```

That lets you safely store a `ProcessorImpl()` in the map.

But you still have to use an (unchecked) cast on the values you pull *out* of the map before you can use them:

```
(map[ActionType.ADD] as IMessageProcessor<IdPayload>)
.process(Message("4", IdPayload(4L)))
```

I don't think there's any easy way around that, because the problem is inherent in having values which are processors that can handle only some (unknown) types of message.

I'm afraid the best thing would be to have a rethink about what these classes mean and how they should interact, and redesign accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear explanation! Would you give me some advice how to deal with that issue? How would you redesign this system?